# Options to create DOM element via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Say I want to create a new DOM element from my javascript/jQuery code, with some properties such as id or class. I have seen a number of different ways to do this, such as:

```
$('<div>').prop('id','someid').addClass('someclass');
$('<div></div>').prop(...).addClass(...);
$("<div id='some' class='someclass'>");
```

And I think I recall seeing an option that passed in a dictionary of properties as well, not to mention any pure javascript options. Of course, the created element would then need to be added to the DOM tree via one of a number of options, but that's a different question.

So the question is: in addition to the above, what are the various options I can use to create a DOM element from code?

EDIT: Please note, I am NOT asking which option is best. Rather, I am trying to find out what my options are when I need to create a DOM element from jQuery code.

Comment: Another option `$('<div />', {'id':'someid', 'class' : 'someclass'});`

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2

Comment: @j08691 Thank you, that is very helpful. In all my searching for create DOM element and the like, I hadn't managed to find that page. If you wanted to post that as an answer, I could accept it.

Comment: @Satpal Ah, yes. That's the other one I was trying to think of.

Comment: So, any one of the apparently numerous people who think this is a bad question care to share why so I can improve in the future?

Answer (score 1):

Best option IMO, is .append.

Say you are creating an overlay or dialog, it is as easy as appending to the body, you can even pass text into a function to make it generic:

```
Function ShowDiag(text)
{
    $('body').append("<div class='customDialog'>"+text+"</div>");
}

Function RemoveDiag()
{
    $('.customDialog').remove();
}
```

Set up a pre-defined CSS style to the customDialog class.

Good luck.

Comment: Yes, this is another option - simply create and add to the DOM tree at the same time. Thanks.